Trying to create a .DLL to take pictures on a USB Camera
I am trying to create a C# UWP dll that I can import into powershell to automate control of simple USB camera (Take photo on command and save to file)
I have found a basic CameraStarterSDK from windows, and have attempted adapting that into a DLL but I dont understand what I am missing or if I am not calling it correctly. Powershell gives the following errors depending on how I try to import it.
Add-type gives me the error:
Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
Reflection Assembly::Loadfile method with $custObj = New-Object CameraClassLibrary.Camera gives error:
Cannot find type [CameraClassLibrary.Camera]: verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded.
Have I built the DLL incorrectly? or Am I calling/using it incorrectly in powershell?
C# DLL Code
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Devices.Enumeration;
using Windows.Graphics.Imaging;
using Windows.Media.Capture;
using Windows.Media.MediaProperties;
using Windows.Storage;
using Windows.Storage.Streams;

namespace CameraClassLibrary
{
    public class Camera
    {

        private StorageFolder _captureFolder = null;
        private MediaCapture _mediaCapture;
        private bool _isInitialized;
        private bool _isPreviewing;
        private bool _isRecording;
        private bool _externalCamera;

        private async Task InitializeCameraAsync()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("InitializeCameraAsync");

            if (_mediaCapture == null)
            {
                // Attempt to get the back camera if one is available, but use any camera device if not
                var cameraDevice = await FindCameraDeviceByPanelAsync(Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel.Back);

                if (cameraDevice == null)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("No camera device found!");
                    return;
                }

                // Create MediaCapture and its settings
                _mediaCapture = new MediaCapture();

                // Register for a notification when video recording has reached the maximum time and when something goes wrong
                _mediaCapture.RecordLimitationExceeded += MediaCapture_RecordLimitationExceeded;
                _mediaCapture.Failed += MediaCapture_Failed;

                var settings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings { VideoDeviceId = cameraDevice.Id };

                // Initialize MediaCapture
                try
                {
                    await _mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(settings);
                    _isInitialized = true;
                }
                catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("The app was denied access to the camera");
                }

                // If initialization succeeded, start the preview
                if (_isInitialized)
                {
                    // Figure out where the camera is located
                    if (cameraDevice.EnclosureLocation == null || cameraDevice.EnclosureLocation.Panel == Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel.Unknown)
                    {
                        // No information on the location of the camera, assume it's an external camera, not integrated on the device
                        _externalCamera = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Camera is fixed on the device
                        _externalCamera = false;

                        // Only mirror the preview if the camera is on the front panel
                    }


                }
            }
        }
        private async Task TakePhotoAsync(string Filename)
        {

            await InitializeCameraAsync();
            var stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();

            Debug.WriteLine("Taking photo...");
            await _mediaCapture.CapturePhotoToStreamAsync(ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg(), stream);

            try
            {
                var file = await _captureFolder.CreateFileAsync(Filename + ".jpg", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
                Debug.WriteLine("Photo taken! Saving to " + file.Path);

                //var photoOrientation = CameraRotationHelper.ConvertSimpleOrientationToPhotoOrientation(_rotationHelper.GetCameraCaptureOrientation());

                await ReencodeAndSavePhotoAsync(stream, file);
                Debug.WriteLine("Photo saved!");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // File I/O errors are reported as exceptions
                Debug.WriteLine("Exception when taking a photo: " + ex.ToString());
            }


        }

        private async Task CleanupCameraAsync()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("CleanupCameraAsync");

            if (_isInitialized)
            {
                // If a recording is in progress during cleanup, stop it to save the recording
                if (_isRecording)
                {
                    await StopRecordingAsync();
                }

                _isInitialized = false;
            }

            if (_mediaCapture != null)
            {
                _mediaCapture.RecordLimitationExceeded -= MediaCapture_RecordLimitationExceeded;
                _mediaCapture.Failed -= MediaCapture_Failed;
                _mediaCapture.Dispose();
                _mediaCapture = null;
            }
        }
        private static async Task ReencodeAndSavePhotoAsync(IRandomAccessStream stream, StorageFile file)
        {
            using (var inputStream = stream)
            {
                var decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(inputStream);

                using (var outputStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
                {
                    var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateForTranscodingAsync(outputStream, decoder);

                    //var properties = new BitmapPropertySet { { "System.Photo.Orientation", new BitmapTypedValue(photoOrientation, PropertyType.UInt16) } };

                    //await encoder.BitmapProperties.SetPropertiesAsync(properties);
                    await encoder.FlushAsync();
                }
            }
        }

        private static async Task<DeviceInformation> FindCameraDeviceByPanelAsync(Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel desiredPanel)
        {
            // Get available devices for capturing pictures
            var allVideoDevices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(DeviceClass.VideoCapture);

            // Get the desired camera by panel
            DeviceInformation desiredDevice = allVideoDevices.FirstOrDefault(x => x.EnclosureLocation != null && x.EnclosureLocation.Panel == desiredPanel);

            // If there is no device mounted on the desired panel, return the first device found
            return desiredDevice ?? allVideoDevices.FirstOrDefault();
        }

        private async void MediaCapture_RecordLimitationExceeded(MediaCapture sender)
        {
            // This is a notification that recording has to stop, and the app is expected to finalize the recording

            await StopRecordingAsync();

        }

        private async void MediaCapture_Failed(MediaCapture sender, MediaCaptureFailedEventArgs errorEventArgs)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("MediaCapture_Failed: (0x{0:X}) {1}", errorEventArgs.Code, errorEventArgs.Message);

            await CleanupCameraAsync();

        }

        private async Task StopRecordingAsync()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Stopping recording...");

            _isRecording = false;
            await _mediaCapture.StopRecordAsync();

            Debug.WriteLine("Stopped recording!");
        }

        public async void TakePhoto(string Filename)
        {
            await TakePhotoAsync(Filename);
        }



    }
}

I would like to call said DLL via Powershell to trigger a USB camera to take a picture and save to disk.

"Add-type gives me the error:
[...] Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information." - so, did you try inspecting the LoaderExceptions property on the exception thrown? :)

How do I inspect the loaderExceptions? Most of my experience is in powershell scripting and I am struggling to figure out where things are inspected/Probed to learn more
